# Why does ie8's user agent return 'opera'?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, opera, user-agent

My code at: http://www.mgxvideo.com/mgxcopy-dev/get_browser.php, returns Opera when I run IE8.  My source is:

```
<?php
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo $browser['browser'];
?>
```

Comment: When I browse to that address using Firefox or IE8, I get 'Default Browser'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't. The `get_browser()` function is making educated (but ill-informed) guesses about which browser the user-agent is running. Your browser capabilities file is likely outdated, probably because it was made before IE8 was released. Update it [**here**](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp).

The real IE8 user-agent string looks something like this:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a lower-level tool, like a packet trace or server logging or a header dump to see what is being sent.